# Android, turn on USB debugging?

Tags: android

I'm currently using a Motorola Nexus 6 that I would like to enable USB debugging on. I did tap the About 7 times to become a developer and I have access to the developer menu. I did enable USB Debugging, but when I connect the phone to the PC it still doesn't work. On my old Nexus 5 I did get a prompt to allowed my PC to debug my android device. But I do not get the same prompt on my Nexus 6, even after I tried to revoke USB debugging authorizations. Not sure what else to try, I tried with another cable, and another USB port. Both 3.0 and 2.0.

Comment: Have you installed appropriate usb drivers ?

Comment: Have you checked in device manager ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) and try restarting the ADB service. I had a similar problem on my Nexus 6 and after rebooting the Device and restarting ADB it worked.